# Optimization techniques for reducing Windows Mobile 6.x OS build time

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

As far as I understand, the OS image build time (initial and incremental) from Windows CE to Windows Mobile has increased significantly. What are some possible things I can do to reduce the compile time for Windows Mobile OS build?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows CE and Windows Mobile OS build time is typically limited by disk I/O bandwidth.  Having the release directory on a high-speed (15k drives) RAID array greatly improves `sysgen` speed.  Using a RAM disk is even better, though often more of a challenge to get IT to implement for you.

That said, it's never super quick.  What kind of times are you seeing right now?  10 minutes?  30 minutes?  It's unlikely you'll get it much under the 10 minute mark no matter what you do (I think the lowest we ever achieved was about 7) , but if you're out at 30 minutes or more, then hardware is going to help.

Bear in mind that you often don't need to do a full `sysgen`.  Often you can use the console window to just `build` the piece you're working on (e.g. a driver), making sure it's set to copy the output to the release directory, and then just call `makeimg`.

Comment: I'm seeing times around 15 minutes for incremental build. Also, what about the array of languages that get compiled as well?